# Calling a stand alone java program from a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a stand alone java program having 'main method' that runs continuously in the background polling for any requests in a socket.

I also have web application that needs to pass specific data to clients that connect to the socket opened by the stand alone java program. Is there a way for me to directly call this java program from my servlet or is this not possible at all since java code is executed by jam and servlet is managed by servlet container?

If this is not possible any other suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks,
V

Comment: How did you end up solving your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any solution that lets you communicate between two processes/JVMs will let you communicate between a servlet and a standalone java process--sockets for example. If your standalone process is already accepting socket connections, have it listen for connections from the servlet as well.

**Update:** Each time you invoke the `java` command (which servlet containers do), you start a new JVM. Two Java processes on the same machine can communicate like any other two processes can. They could write to files, communicate to a common database, whatever. Being Java processes, you could also use JMX to communicate. There are plenty of other off-the-wall options, too. You're really limited only by your imagination. If I were doing it, I'd probably embed a lightweight HTTP server in the standalone process and use HTTP for communication because it's just simple. Some easily embeddable servers include [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php), [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding+Jetty), and [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/quickstart.html).

Comment: So , does his mean both servlet and my java program run on different JVM even if they are in the same machine? Is there any way of achieving this without using sockets? Thanks a lot.This helps.

Comment: @Vicky: Updated my answer. Let me know if that answers your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does ,but I still have a question. Sorry, if I am sounding stupid.There a java virtual machine installed in the machine. A java program is converted to byte code and is executed by the same JVM for all the stand alone programs. Does the servlet not use this JVM? I thought it will be executed by the same JVM even though it runs in a servlet container. Is my assumption incorrect? Can Simple , Jetty and Grizzly be used by having a tomcat server instead of a full fledged application server?Thank You , I will definitely try the option suggested by you.

Comment: Okay, the JVM is installed on the machine once, but every time you run `java`, you spawn a new *instance* of the JVM. Compare it to the command prompt on Windows. It exists on disk one time, but every time you run `cmd`, it pops up a new prompt, and you get a new "cmd" in your process list. Same thing with Java. Every time you run `java`, it runs the "same" JVM, but a different instance of it. I suggest you ask a new question with this as the subject to see if you can clarify it for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This does clarify.